# Using NyARToolkit is it possible to get distance between camera and the marker?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I am doing a class project on Android OS 1.6. I am considering to use NyARToolkit (Java implementation of ARToolkit for Android). I need to know whether it is possible to get the distance between the camera and a fiducial marker. If possible, how can I get it?

Please help.

Comment: Does the marker have latt/long data associated with it?

Comment: yes, it is allowed to put latt/long data on the marker (don't know how, I am new in it)

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you know that marker position. All you have to do, is to have a calibration phase to convert the distance in points (obtained from NyARToolkit) to distance of your desired units.